# Using the UPDATE MySQL Command in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms, visual-studio

Suppose I have this method from one class:

```
private void btnChangeImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var openFileDialogForImgUser = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        string location = null;
        string fileName = null;
        openFileDialogForImgUser.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg, *.png, *.gif, *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.png; *.gif; *.bmp|All Files (*.*)|*.*"; // filtering only picture file types
        var openFileResult = openFileDialogForImgUser.ShowDialog(); // show the file open dialog box
        if (openFileResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var formSaveImg = new FormSave())
            {
                var saveResult = formSaveImg.ShowDialog();
                if (saveResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    imgUser.Image = new Bitmap(openFileDialogForImgUser.FileName); //showing the image opened in the picturebox
                    location = openFileDialogForImgUser.FileName;
                    fileName = openFileDialogForImgUser.SafeFileName;

                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); //Creating a filestream to open the image file
                    int fileLength = (int)fs.Length; // getting the length of the file in bytes
                    byte[] rawdata = new byte[fileLength]; // creating an array to store the image as bytes
                    fs.Read(rawdata, 0, (int)fileLength); // using the filestream and converting the image to bits and storing it in an array

                    MySQLOperations MySQLOperationsObj = new MySQLOperations("localhost", "root", "myPass");
                    MySQLOperationsObj.saveImage(rawdata);
                    fs.Close();
                }
                else
                    openFileDialogForImgUser.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this method from another class (MySQLOperations):

```
public void saveImage(byte[] rawdata)
{
    try
    {
        string myConnectionString = "Data Source = " + server + "; User = " + user + "; Port = 3306; Password = " + password + ";";
        MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
        string currentUser = FormLogin.userID;
        string useDataBaseCommand = "USE " + dbName + ";";
        string updateTableCommand = "UPDATE tblUsers SET UserImage = @file WHERE Username = \'" + currentUser + "\';";
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(useDataBaseCommand + updateTableCommand, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", rawdata);
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

If I must, this is my constructor for the MySQLOperations class:

```
public MySQLOperations(string server, string user, string password)
{
    this.server = server;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is save an image file (which the user selects through the open file dialog box) to the database. Problem is I get this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';UPDATE tblUsers SET UserImage = _binary'?PNG ... (and so on with some random characters). So, I can't really save the file in the database. I would love to post a picture on how the error is seen at the MessageBox, but I guess my account is not given the privilege to do so yet.

I'm not really sure where the syntax error is in that. I'm thinking, it's in the @file - but that's just a guess. Your help would be very much appreciated.
And oh, the table column UserImage has a type of LONGBLOB.

Other things I'm interested to know about also:

- Is it necessary that I add another column for my table to store the
  size of the file (because I'm going to need to retrieve the file
  to display the image later on)?
- Is it okay that I used the using statement that way in the method
  btnChangeImage_Click?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Got the problem solved. Such a simple thing not given attention to. Thanks to everybody who tried to help. I'm still willing to hear your opinion on the questions at the bottom (those on bullets).

Comment: Why don't you parameterize your `username` value as you did with `@file`?

Comment: Yes, yes. Good point. I applied that, but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure dbName has a value?  Otherwise your statement would be: USE ;UPDATE ...

Comment: Ok. That simple suggestion did it. Thanks. I overlooked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the following line of code:

```
WHERE Username = \'" + currentUser + "\';"
```

It should change to the following one:

```
WHERE Username = " + currentUser;
```

Or better (to avoid sql injections) to the following one:

```
WHERE Username = @Username";
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", currentUser);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to solve the problem. Thanks for trying though, and I'm gonna use your tip.

Comment: @Jill you welcome dude. I will take a look again in your code and If I find something, I will let you know. Otherwise, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store binary files in a MySQL table. Instead, save it to disk and save path to PNG file to MySQL database. Also, use Christos advice to avoid SQL injections.